# Tailwind Not compiling

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I am trying to follow along to a YT video about building a react website using Tailwind https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_oO4Qi5aVZs. I know certain pieces will be out of date (i.e. using content rather than purge in the config etc).

However, I cannot my website to display any CSS. For reference the config file and the top of the CSS file are below.

Config File

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./index.html", "./src/**/*.{js,jsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        primary: '#00040f',
        secondary: "#00f6ff",
        dimWhite: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)",
        dimBlue: "rgba(9, 151, 124, 0.1)",
      },
      fontFamily: {
        poppins: ["Poppins", "sans-serif"],
      },
    },
    screens: {
      xs: "480px",
      ss: "620px",
      sm: "768px",
      md: "1060px",
      lg: "1200px",
      xl: "1700px",
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap");

@import 'tailwindcss/base';
@import 'tailwindcss/components';
@import 'tailwindcss/utilities';

:root {
  --black-gradient: linear-gradient(
    144.39deg,
    #ffffff -278.56%,
    #6d6d6d -78.47%,
    #11101d 91.61%
  );
  --card-shadow: 0px 20px 100px -10px rgba(66, 71, 91, 0.1);
}

* {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

I have tried to amend my tailwind as per the up to date docs. But this doesn't seem to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Two things you might need to check:

1. Do you have your tailwind css file linked at the root of your website? Sometimes I forget to link and then wonder why my styles are not loading :grin:
2. I'm not sure how your project is structured, but maybe you need to update the filepaths in your tailwind config and run `npm run dev`  again?

Maybe if you post more information about your component folder structure, and App.js, I might be able to help further..